# How does laravel 4 know what to do with 'showWelcome' method?

Tags: php, controller, laravel, laravel-4

So, to keep this short, how does laravel know what to do in the default controller when it sees the method 'showWelcome' ?

in routes there is

`Route::get('/', function() { return View::make('hello'); });`

which is fine, but how does it now to act on `showWelcome`.. where is that set in configs? could it be named something else?

Comment: Why do you think it is using showWelcome anywhere?

Comment: the showWelcome is a placeholder example in the controller iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going by the default install of Laravel 4 (at the current time), the `showWelcome` method isn't actually fired on the `HomeController` controller for this route. However, the method would return the same thing as the route.

You could fire this method by changing to route to the following:

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');`

Comment: Yes.  I came from using Yii/Codeigniter and was used to the method name in the controller being what is accessed when you want to call it. i.e. domain.com/somecontroller/somemethod. Thanks.